# qt - In QGraphicsScene I can't get the correct Item

Tags: qt

I am trying to create a chessboard. All the coins are transparent and the board is not. When I tried to get the clicked item using the function 'itemAt' it always returning the backGround item(that means the board). I am suspecting that due to the fact that the coins are transparent, they are not selected.

Comment: When you say the items are transparent do you mean they are not visible (i.e. QWidget.isVisible() returns false)?  itemAt() only returns the items that are visible.  It also returns the topmost item.  Try items(const QPointF& pos) to get all the items at a point regardless of z order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer. I tried to get the `event->pos()`. This will return the mouse click in the `QGraphicsItem`'s coordinates. So I should use `event->scenePos()`.

Now I am getting it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your own custom `QGraphicsItem` then you may need to override [`shape()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#shape),

If it's a plain `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and it has an alpha mask, then you need to call [`setShapeMode()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#setShapeMode).