# QGraphicsScene::itemAt() return wrong item

Tags: python, qt

I'm writing a GUI program with PyQT. The program has a QGraphicsScene with some items in it. There is a large rect and afterwards a few bitmaps (by calling addPixmap()) are added inside of it. I'm trying to remove some bitmaps under some situation. So I uses itemAt() API to get the graphics item. The problem is that it always return the rect object. I tried to use setZvalue() on the bitmap object as well but didn't make a difference.

Here are some code. When adding bitmap:

```
    gi = QGraphicsPixmapItem(bitmap())
    print "setPos(%d,%d)" % (x,y)
    gi.setPos(x, y)
    gi.setZValue(5)
    self.scene.addItem(gi)
```

When removing:

```
    gi = self.scene.itemAt(x, y)
    print "remove(%d,%d)" % (x, y)
    self.scene.removeItem(gi)
```

I can see that the (x, y) pair are the same for addition and removal.

What's the trick here?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't use PyQt, but are you possibly using `pos()` instead of `scenePos()` as a parameter to `itemAt()`, as in this question?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086374/qt-in-qgraphicsscene-i-cant-get-the-correct-item

Comment: the removal is not mouse event driven. So i don't think it's the case. I've added some code above.

Comment: Code always helps.  :)  Have you tried setting it up so the rectangle is a parent of the bitmap graphics items (instead of a lower z-ordered peer in the item list) to see if that makes a difference?